# ValueChange Event in GWT having multiple attributes

Tags: gwt

I have 2 class ATable and ARow.
There is an attribute Column colPauseDate in Class ATable.

I want to add a value change Event on colPauseDate, Such that on change of date do Something.

How can it be done in GWT? Kindly help

Comment: sorry attribute is  Column<ARow,Date> colPauseDate;

Comment: How the date can be changed? Are you using cell editors? Is Column your own class or is it com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column?

Comment: Yes I am using cell Editor and Column is from com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column.  Actually the main problem which I am facing is, colPauseDate is a DatePicker and when I am selecting the date it is reverting back to Default date which I have set ,once the Page is refreshed. So ,basically what I want is to keep the selected date displaying in the column.

Comment: Better update your question instead of answering in comment, also adding codesnippets of the colums and such might help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `FieldUpdater` for `colPauseDate` column:

```
colPauseDate.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ARow, Date>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, ARow object, Date value) {
        object.setDate(value);  // update object value
        redrawRow(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I am using FieldUpdater and instead of redrawRow(index) , I have written cellTable.redraw();

Comment: So selected value is displaying until the page is reloaded or refreshed..